# DJI CrystalSky - Toast Messages no showing (intermittent)

Tags: android, toast, dji-sdk

I have written an App using the Mobile and Android SDK (based on the sample app).
However on when the app runs on a DJI Crystal Sky, it frequently happens that no Toast Messages get displayed.

Patterns:
 - They work fine on other devices.
 - If they work, they work continuously while the app runs.
 - If they don't work, they won't show up at all.
 - The best way to get them to show is to reinstall the app.
 - Changing notification settings on the Crystal Sky had no effect for me.

Has anyone else come across this issue and found a way to solve it?
It seems like DJI use Toast messages in DJI Go and Go4 where they show reliably. I.e.: there must be a way to get them to work.

P.S: I already looked into Snackbar and other libraries, but they are by far not as versatile which is why I would like to stick to Toast if possible.

**EDIT 29/04/2019**
I have just noticed that the same behaviour is observed in other Apps (ES file explorer).

Probably not fixable in code and a bug in the Crystal Sky's software.

**EDIT 02/07/2019**
As it was pointed out by Milanka in the comments,
the Crystal Sky automatically disables Notifications for apps which hides Toast messages.
On my units it happens after each reboot.

Comment: Are you sure it is a problem with the Toast itself, and not error in the logic behind showing the Toast. Try to add a log right before showing a Toast.
Also, what's wrong with Snackbar?

Comment: No issues and nothing weird that's printed in the log. 
I already log every toast message and they show up in logcat just fine.

What's wrong with Snackbar?
It hasn't been playing well with DJI's UX SDK and it's requirement of being attached to a view makes it cumbersome to use in utility classes that are not directly part of the UI.
Toasts just render on top and fade away.

Comment: This enables them temporarily for me, but unfortunately I don't know what disables them after a while: Settings -> Apps -> ALL -> your_app_name -> Show notifications

Comment: Thanks, sadly however this won't work for me as I need a permanent solution.

Comment: @Milanka I've just checked on one of our CyrstalSky's and noticed that it disables this checkbox after every reboot.